# Python - RobotFramework - Getting none on query result

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm making a test using a query (I am using Execute SQL String instead of row count for now) to count the number of rows with the following code:

```
*** Settings ***
Library     DatabaseLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem

*** Variables ***
${DBName}   db
${DBUser}   user
${DBPass}   password
${DBHost}   hostname
${DBPort}   port

*** Test Cases ***
Making row count
    DatabaseLibrary.Connect To Database       pymysql    ${DBName}    ${DBUser}    ${DBPass}    ${DBHost}    ${DBPort}
    ${result} =  Execute SQL String  SELECT COUNT(*) as count_id FROM myTable;  True
    should be equal as strings  ${result}   6
    Disconnect From Database
```

If I go to my database I return 6 rows, so the test should me passed. However, using RobotFramework I am getting the following results:

```
==============================================================================
Making row count                                                     | FAIL |
None != 6
```

Why I am using None as result? I am using Execute SQL String because I have the same code for other tests with some more complex SQL Queries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of rows will be returned by Execute SQL keywords. Data returns will be done only through **Query** keyword. Please try to use :

```
${rows}=  Query   SELECT COUNT(*) as count_id FROM myTable;
should be equal as strings  ${rows}   6
```

or

```
 @{results}    Query    ${yourQuery}
```